# getLoginStatus and getAuthResponse not working in IE

Tags: facebook, browser

I have search in Facebook docs and here in StackOverflow and none of the posible solutions works for me. The code works in Firefox and Chrome and even in Internet Explorer when the page is not loaded inside the canvas iFrame, but in app canvas iFrame these functions never call its callbacks, thus Neither `getUserData` nor `fbAskAuth()` are ever called. As you can see I have filled the channelUrl param. This is my code:

```
var fb = {};

fb = function(){

  var pub = {};
  var priv = {};
  var base_url = '{base_url}';

  //atributes
  pub.user = {};
  pub.token = {};

  //methods
  pub.init = function(callback)
  {
      //When the library has loaded, it calls this function
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        //Facebook jsSDK inizalization
        FB.init({
          appId  : '{app_id}',
          channelUrl: base_url + 'res/channel.php',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          oauth: true
        });

        //Resize the iframe
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 760, height: ($('body').outerHeight(true) + 50) });

        // Check for the user session
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if (response.status === 'connected')
            {
                // This user has already authorized the app
                priv.getUserData(response, callback);
            }
            else
            {
               // No user session available, this is a new user to the app
               // or a user not logued in facebook
               priv.fbAskAuth(callback);
           }
        });

      };

      //Asyncronous get of facebook library.
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

  };

  pub.inviteSendGeneral = function()
  {
      FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: pub.user.name+' te ha invitado a participar en La Porra de GOLT.',
                data: 'tracking info'
            }, function(requests){
                $.ajax({
                       url: base_url + 'ajax/invite/',
                       type: 'post',
                       data: {fuid: pub.user.id, invitation: requests },
                       success: function(resp)
                       {
                           $('#help-msg').html(resp);
                       }
                  });
            });
  }

  pub.inviteSend = function()
  {
      FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: pub.user.name+' te ha invitado a participar en una porra.',
                data: 'tracking info'
            }, function(requests){
                if(requests !== undefined)
                {
                    for(var i=0; i<requests.request_ids.length; i++)
                    {
                        FB.api(requests.request_ids[i], {access_token: pub.user.access_token}, function(request_obj){

                            $.ajax({
                                   url: base_url + 'ajax/friends_invite/',
                                   type: 'post',
                                   data: {fuid: pub.user.id, invitation: request_obj.id, invited: request_obj.to.id, round: pub.getId($('.invite-friends').attr('id'))},
                                   success: function(resp){
                                       $('#help-msg').html(resp);
                                   }
                              });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
  }

  priv.getUserData = function(response, callback)
  {
     FB.api('/me', {access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken}, function(user_data) {

        if(user_data.id != '0'){
            pub.user = user_data;
            pub.token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            callback.call();
        }else{
            priv.fbAskAuth(callback);
        }
     });
  };

  pub.checkLikes = function(likes, page_id)
  {
          //var likes = $.parseJSON(data);
          for(var i=0; i<likes.data.length; i++)
          {
            if(likes.data[i].id == page_id){
                return true;
            }
          }
      return false;
  }

  priv.fbAskAuth = function(callback)
  {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {

          priv.getUserData(response, callback);

      } else {
        // user is not logged in
        priv.fbAskAuth(callback);
      }
    }, {scope:'{app_perms}'});
  };

  pub.array2str = function(requests)
  {
    var result_str = '';
    for(var i=0; i < requests.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == requests.length-1)
            result_str = result_str + requests[i];
        else
            result_str = result_str + requests[i] + ',';
    }

    return result_str;
  };

  pub.getId = function(str)
  {
    var id_array = str.split('_');
    return id_array[id_array.length-1];
  };

  return pub;

}();
```

At another js file, I call fb.init as well as I include other objects and functions. Everything works fine, except getLoginStatus which is not calling its callback

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fb.init(function(){
        if($('.penaltis').length > 0)
        {
            loadFriends();
        }
    });

});
```

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in most cases there is two typical problem make all the trouble. The first one, is that Facebook call your app URL with https anyway. The second is to forget to define . Have you checked your page with https://?

Comment: Yes, I have ssl credentials and https up and working with this and others apps, I have tried http:// and https:// and checked that when in https:// every request have https://

Comment: I suggest to put an <fb:like></fb:like> button somewhere to see the javascript is working. Of course there is million solution to find out, may be this is the quickest one. Anyway, you sould have error message on the console (hopefully).

Comment: javascript is working, other javascript listeners are working and facebook dialogs work ok. I think I will do a workaround and add some code to get the data from php in this browser...